# Parameter 0 of method createScore in thesisMongoProject.controller.ScoreController required a bean of type 'thesisMongoProject.Score'

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I used Spring Boot rest api with MongoDb.
I have four classes, Player Class, Games Class, History Class and Score Class.
I used Embedded documents with Spring Data and MongoDB and in my Project, I want create a new score in POST Method, for existing Player and GameCode.
But I have this Error and cannot understand why?

The Score Class:

```
    package thesisMongoProject;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;

@Document(collection = "score")
public class Score {
    @Id
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String scoreID;
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String score;
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private Player player;
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private Games gamecode;
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private Date date;
    private List<History> history;



    public Score(@NotBlank String scoreID, @NotBlank String score, @NotBlank Player player, @NotBlank Games gamecode,
            Date date, List<History> history) {
        super();
        this.scoreID = scoreID;
        this.score = score;
        this.player = player;
        this.gamecode = gamecode;
        this.date = date;
        this.history = history;
    }
    public String getScoreID() {
        return scoreID;
    }
    public void setScoreID(String scoreID) {
        this.scoreID = scoreID;
    }
    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
    public Games getGamecode() {
        return gamecode;
    }
    public void setGamecode(Games gamecode) {
        this.gamecode = gamecode;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public List<History> getHistory() {
        return history;
    }
    public void setHistory(List<History> history) {
        this.history = history;
    }







}
```

The Player Class:

```
    package thesisMongoProject;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "player")
public class Player {
    @Id
    @NotBlank
    private String nickname;
    @NotBlank
    private String firstname;
    @NotBlank
    private String lastname;
    @NotBlank
    private String email;

    public Player(String nickname, String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
        super();
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }
    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player [nickname=" + nickname + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", email="
                + email + "]";
    }


}
```

The Games Class:

```
    package thesisMongoProject;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;


@Document(collection = "game")
public class Games {
    @Id
    @NotBlank
    private String code;
    @NotBlank
    private String title;
    @NotBlank
    private String software_house;
    @NotBlank
    private String version;
    @NotBlank
    private String release_year;
    public Games(@NotBlank String code, @NotBlank String title, @NotBlank String software_house,
            @NotBlank String version, @NotBlank @NotBlank @NotBlank String release_year) {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.title = title;
        this.software_house = software_house;
        this.version = version;
        this.release_year = release_year;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getSoftware_house() {
        return software_house;
    }
    public void setSoftware_house(String software_house) {
        this.software_house = software_house;
    }
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    public @NotBlank String getRelease_year() {
        return release_year;
    }
    public void setRelease_year(@NotBlank String release_year) {
        this.release_year = release_year;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Games [code=" + code + ", title=" + title + ", software_house=" + software_house + ", version="
                + version + ", release_year=" + release_year + "]";
    }


}
```

The History Class:

```
    package thesisMongoProject;

import java.util.Date;

public class History {  

        private String score;
        private Date date;




        public History(String score, Date date) {
            super();
            this.score = score;
            this.date = date;
        }



        public String getScore() {
            return score;
        }



        public void setScore(String score) {
            this.score = score;
        }



        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }



        public void setDate(Date date) {
            this.date = date;
        }



        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "History [score=" + score + ", date=" + date + "]";
        }








}
```

The View Class:

```
    package thesisMongoProject;

public class Views {
    public static class Creat{}

}
```

The Score Repository:

```
    package thesisMongoProject.Repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import thesisMongoProject.Games;
import thesisMongoProject.Player;
import thesisMongoProject.Score;

@Repository
public interface ScoreRepository extends MongoRepository<Score, String>{


    public List<Score> findByScore(String score);

    @Query("{'player.nickname':?0}")
    public List<Score> findByPlayerName(Player player);

    @Query("{'gamecode.code':?0}")
    public List<Score> findByGameCode(Games game);
}
```

And the POST Method:

```
 @RestController
@RequestMapping("/score")
public class ScoreController {
    @Autowired
    private ScoreRepository srepo;
    @Autowired
    //private List<History> history;


    //Create Score
        @PostMapping
        public ResponseEntity<?> createScore(@RequestBody @JsonView(Views.class)   Score score) {
            //String player = score.getNickname();
            //String code = score.getCode();
            List<Score> p = srepo.findByPlayerName(score.getPlayer());
            List<Score> g = srepo.findByGameCode(score.getGamecode());
            if ((p.isEmpty())&&(g.isEmpty()))
                return ResponseEntity.status(400).body("Bad Request!");
            else {
                srepo.save(score);
                return ResponseEntity.ok(score);
            }


        }
```

And the error in my console is:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of method createScore in thesisMongoProject.controller.ScoreController required a bean of type 'thesisMongoProject.Score' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody(required=true)
    - @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView({thesisMongoProject.Views.class})


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'thesisMongoProject.Score' in your configuration.
```

could you helpme, what is my mistake,please

Comment: Is that successfully compiled?  and you have to give a mapping name to `@PostMapping`. Eg `@PostMapping("/create")` . Then call it `"/score/create"` in postman or swagger thats your wish

Comment: no it is not compile successfully. i have an error on my console.   this error:   Parameter 0 of method createScore in thesisMongoProject.controller.ScoreController required a bean of type 'thesisMongoProject.Score' that could not be found

Comment: Aslo for Post, in RequestMapping I pointed that "/create", so i think it is not important in PostMapping I do mapping name. by the way i did but nothing chnged

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, in the Score Controller after defining an instance of Score Repository,

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/score")
    public class ScoreController {
        @Autowired
        private ScoreRepository  srepo;
        @Autowired
```

I wrote a annotation @Autowired without using, so when i deleted this unusing @Autowired annotation, anything runs well.